# Spyder very slow on Windows 10

Tags: python, conda, spyder

I have Spyder IDE 5.1.5 on Windows 10 and i use Miconda 3 in Python Interpreter.

Also, i have:

> conda version 4.10.3

,

> python 3.8.12

,

> ipykernel 6.4.2

There is  a very lagging time when i type text in the editor and Spyder is very slow.

I note that this problem does not occur when i do not use Conda in the Python Intepreter, basically simply i change to Python 3.7.

How can i resolve this?

Comment: Same behavior on MacOS 12.4 arm64.